# Why client program can read user's cloud data through Google Drive API even after deleting all projects from developer console of my account?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

Why the client program can read user's Google Drive Data through Google Drive API even after deleting all Google Cloud Platform Projects of my account?

Is it something like that?

Is it possible to prevent user from using the client program?

Source code.

```cs
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GoogleDriveTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string[] Scopes = {
                                      DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                                      DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                                      DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata
                                  };
        private const string ApplicationName = "Quickstart";

        private UserCredential credential;
        public DriveService service;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetAuth();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string x = GetFile("DocumentName");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void GetAuth()
        {
            using (var stream = 
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
                        ).Result;
                //_userCredential = credentials.Result;

                //if (credentials.IsCanceled || credentials.IsFaulted)
                //    throw new Exception("cannot connect");

                service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });
            }
        }

        public string GetFile(string file_name)
        {
            FilesResource.ListRequest req = service.Files.List();

            do
            {
                //req.Q = "title='" + file_name + "'";
                req.Q = "name='" + file_name + "'";
                FileList file_search = req.Execute();
                foreach (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File a in file_search.Files)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(a.Id);
                    return a.Id;
                }
            } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.PageToken));
            return "";
        }


    }
}
```

..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........

Comment: did you delete the project in Google developer console?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think yes I do.

Comment: Hi there @first! I can't fully understand the context of the question. Could you please share the call and request that you refer to? To rule out a propagation problem, how long ago was the project deleted?

Comment: It was one or two hours ago.

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron, Thanks for your comment. One or two hours ago, I deleted all the projects from Google Developer Console.

Comment: @first Due to the small amount of time elapsed from the deletion, it may be a propagation problem. Could you please confirm if you are still facing the issue?